# Returning location within a circle circumference

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to do circle approximation that is a regular polygon with N corners using d3.js.

My idea was to always have a circle in the background and use the "transform" function to slide around the circle and obtain a position (x,y), which I would pass to a polygon.

For example, if I must have the circle divided in 3 parts, it would become a triangle. With that, I would rotate within the circle 3 times starting at (0,0) and return the position of the two other points within the circumference of the circle.

My problem is that the "transform" function does not return me a x,y coordinate.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var originX = 200;
var originY = 200;
var outerCircleRadius = 60;


var outerCircle = svg.append("circle").attr({
    cx: originX,
    cy: originY,
    r: outerCircleRadius,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "black"
});

var chairOriginX = originX + ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.sin(0));
var chairOriginY = originY - ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.cos(0));

var chairWidth = 20;

console.log(chairOriginX);
console.log(chairOriginY);

var chair = svg.append("rect").attr({
    x: chairOriginX - (chairWidth / 2),
    y: chairOriginY - (chairWidth / 2),
    width: chairWidth,
    opacity: 1,
    height: 20,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "blue"
});


var chairOriginX2 = originX + ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.sin(0));
var chairOriginY2 = originY - ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.cos(0));
console.log(chairOriginX2);
console.log(chairOriginY2);


var chair2 = svg.append("rect").attr({
    x: chairOriginX2 - (chairWidth / 2),
    y: chairOriginY2 - (chairWidth / 2),
    width: chairWidth,
    opacity: 1,
    height: 50,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "red"
});

var n_number = 5
var n_angles = 360/n_number
var angle_start=0;
var angle_next;

chair2.attr("transform", "rotate(" + (angle_start+n_angles+n_angles) + ", 200, 200)");
console.log(chair2.attr("transform", "rotate(" + (angle_start+n_angles+n_angles) + ", 200, 200)"));



var chairOriginX3 = originX + ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.sin(0));
var chairOriginY3 = originY - ((outerCircleRadius) * Math.cos(0));
console.log(chairOriginX3);
console.log(chairOriginY3);

var chair3 = svg.append("rect").attr({
    x: chairOriginX3 - (chairWidth / 2),
    y: chairOriginY3 - (chairWidth / 2),
    width: chairWidth,
    opacity: 1,
    height: 50,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "black"
});

var n_number = 5
var n_angles = 360/n_number
var angle_start=0;
var angle_next;

chair3.attr("transform", "rotate(" + (angle_start+n_angles+n_angles+n_angles) + ", 200, 200)");
console.log(chair3.attr("transform", "rotate(" + (angle_start+n_angles+n_angles+n_angles) + ", 200, 200)"));
```

Comment: I can't find your getter. Where is it?

Comment: I am new to JavaScript but are you asking about the display the data from the object? If yes, on my HTML side I am calling "<script src="myScript.js"></script> " where myScript.js is the file that I pasted on the question.

Comment: No, no, you said *"my problem is that the 'transform' function does not return me a x,y coordinate"*. Where is the getter that returns the transform value? In short: where is the problematic line?

Comment: transform adds a matrix to the matrix stack

Comment: For me, when I use "chair3.attr(", I was hoping to get a x,y (representing the pixels) where that rotation leads me. However, I get "<rect x=\"190\" y=\"130\" width=\"20\" opacity=\"1\" height=\"50\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" transform=\"rotate(216, 200, 200)\"></rect>" which does bring me any (x,y) that I can use on my polygon.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, the second option worked!! I was looking for the (x,y) coordinates in a reference to the whole element SVG. That's it. Thank you!